# Вычислить суму бесконечного ряда с точность e=0.5*10^-4

Tags: математика, pascal, ряды

[image: Помогите очень срочно]

Помогите очень срочно
Вычислить суму бесконечного ряда с точность e=0.5*10^-4
Не знаю как решить совсем а сдать надо очень скоро

Comment: очень срочно в воскресенье началось? а в субботу почему не начиналось? в чем именно у вас сложности с данной задачей? что именно вы в ней не понимаете и не можете сделать? Если вам совсем срочно - то лучше на фриланс.ру перейти

Comment: Моя задача сдать это до 10 числа. А я совершенно не понимаю как решать данную задачу. По этому обратился за помощью на данный сайт, в надежде что помогут тут

Answer (score 4):

Выполняем несколько простейших преобразований...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После чего написать [программу](https://ideone.com/T5Sj5W) становится совсем просто:

```
program Series;
begin
    WriteLn(1);
end.
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь. Но мне надо показать действия в программе

Comment: Ну, тогда сделайте что-нибудь самостоятельно :) Домашки за вас здесь делать не станут... Проведите на сайте поиск, например, по метке `[ряды]` и посмотрите, как это обычно делается...

Comment: К сожалению если бы я смог сделать это сам, то не обратился за помощью